# matplotlib for loop to show, save and redraw all plots

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

Here's my python code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import savefig


a = np.genfromtxt('do_cv.csv', skiprows = 1, delimiter = ',')
for i in xrange(2):
    t = a[i+1:(i+1)*60, 2]
    z = a[i+1:(i+1)*60, 3]
    est_z = a[i+1:(i+1)*60, 6]
    figure(i+1)
    plt.plot(t, z, 'bo-', t, est_z, 'go-')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('data value')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend(['sample data', 'estimated sample data'])
    plt.savefig('test + str(i).png')


plt.show()
```

then 2 windows come out, like this,

[image]
[image]

figure 2 contains plots of figure 1, how to redraw the plot before the second loop begins?
And I only got 1 png file saved in my folder.

How to modify my code and get the result I want? Please give me some suggestions, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write your self a helper function:

```
def my_plotter(ax, t, z, est_z):
    ln1 = ax.plot(t, z, 'bo-', label='sample data')
    ln2 = ax.plot(t, est_z, 'go-', label='estimated sample data')
    ax.xlabel('time')
    ax.ylabel('data value')
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.legend()
    return ln1 + ln2

for i in xrange(2):
    # get the data
    t = a[i+1:(i+1)*60, 2]
    z = a[i+1:(i+1)*60, 3]
    est_z = a[i+1:(i+1)*60, 6]
    # make the figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # do the plot
    my_plotter(ax, t, z, est_Z)
    # save
    fig.savefig('test_{}.png'.format(i))
```

Now if you decide you want to put both of these is one figure as sub-plots, all you have to do is:

```
# make one figure with 2 axes
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(1, 2)

for i, ax in zip(xrange(2), ax_lst):
    # get the data
    t = a[i+1:(i+1)*60, 2]
    z = a[i+1:(i+1)*60, 3]
    est_z = a[i+1:(i+1)*60, 6]
    # do the plot
    my_plotter(ax, t, z, est_Z)
# save the figure with both plots
fig.savefig('both.png')
```

Comment: I have tried both of your code, but I still got the same result in the second fig, which contained points in the first fig.

Comment: That is because you r selection of data is also wrong. You are pulling out [1:60] and then [2:120]

Answer (score 3):

You overwrite your png file every iteration of the loop, that's why you only have one.

```
    plt.savefig('test + str(i).png')
```

Should be

```
    plt.savefig('test ' + str(i) + '.png')
```